# Spark dataframe explode deprecation warning in 2.4.4

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the latest version of Spark (2.4.4) and it shows a warning regarding deprecation of`explode`. Please suggest an efficient replacement for the following simple use case:

```
scala> val myDF = Seq((1.2, "a b c d"), (2.1, "b g cc"), (4.4, "a b g cc")).toDF("time", "sentence")
myDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [time: double, sentence: string]

scala> val wordsDF = myDF.explode("sentence","word")((line: String) => line.split(" ")).groupBy("word").count().filter($"count" > 1).show
<console>:25: warning: method explode in class Dataset is deprecated: use flatMap() or select() with functions.explode() instead
       val wordsDF = myDF.explode("sentence","word")((line: String) => line.split(" ")).groupBy("word").count().filter($"count" > 1).show
                          ^
+----+-----+
|word|count|
+----+-----+
|  cc|    2|
|   g|    2|
|   b|    3|
|   a|    2|
+----+-----+

wordsDF: Unit = ()

scala>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the deprecation warning suggests, you can either use the [org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#explode) function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, split}
myDF.select(explode(split($"sentence", " ")) as "word").groupBy("word").count().filter($"count" > 1).show
/*
+----+-----+
|word|count|
+----+-----+
|  cc|    2|
|   g|    2|
|   b|    3|
|   a|    2|
+----+-----+
*/
```

or use a Dataset and flatMap():

```scala
case class InData(time: Double, sentence: String)
case class OutData(word: String)
myDF.as[InData].flatMap(d => d.sentence.split(' ').map(OutData)).groupBy("word").count().filter($"count" > 1).show

/*
+----+-----+
|word|count|
+----+-----+
|  cc|    2|
|   g|    2|
|   b|    3|
|   a|    2|
+----+-----+
*/
```